# LINQ to XML Example that Excludes Elements where Descendants Contains Value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new to LINQ to XML and was wondering if anyone could help me construct the following query.

I want to return all the `<response>` elements that do not contain a descendant `<status>` element that contains "404".

My XML is shown below. In this case, only the first `<response>` element (and descendants) should be returned.

```xml
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
  <response>
    <href>/principals/users/test/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <calendar-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
          <href xmlns="DAV:">/calendars/__uids__/d817aaec-7d24-5b38-bc2f-6369da72cdd9</href>
        </calendar-home-set>
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
  <response>
    <href>/principals/users/test/calendar-proxy-write/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <calendar-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" />
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
  <response>
    <href>/principals/users/test/calendar-proxy-read/</href>
    <propstat>
      <prop>
        <calendar-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav" />
      </prop>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
    </propstat>
  </response>
</multistatus>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your XML is stored in the string variable `xml`:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var responsesExcept404s = document
    .Descendants(ns + "response")
    .Where(x => !x.Descendants(ns + "status")
                  .Single()
                  .Value.Contains("404"));
```

Notice the usage of `ns` variable - since your XML has default namespace set via `xmlns` attribute, it is necessary to specify that namespace when using LINQ to XML (such as in `Descendants()` method).

Then you can simply iterate over results and, to make this super-useful, output them to the console:

```
responsesExcept404s.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Hmm... Did you test this? For me, I get empty results. For the namespace, I'm using "DAV:".

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes, I did. I used exactly the XML from your question. My whole program is a simple .NET 4.0 C# console application that consists of storing the XML to the string variable and the code in my answer, nothing more. You should get a single `response` back.

Comment: Doh! Looks like I had the namespace wrong. Your code works as advertised!

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("DAV:");
var responses = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "status")
                    .Where(s => !s.Value.Contains(" 404 "))
                    .Select(s => s.Parent.Parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go: (cheating with XPath)

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new FileStream("XMLFile2.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        XPathNavigator nav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);            
        nsm.AddNamespace("s", "DAV:");
        var nodes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("s:multistatus/s:response[.//*[name(.)='status' and .='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found']]", nsm);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks "hairy". :) Won't work directly in my case because I have an `XElement` rather than an `XDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Document doc = XDocument.Load(path);
       XNamespace nsd = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var res = doc.Descendants(nsd +"response");                

        var filteredEle = new List<XElement>();

                    foreach (var ele in res)
                    {
                        if (CheckEle(ele,nsd))
                        {
                            filteredEle.Add(ele);
                        }
                    }    


    private bool CheckEle(XElement ele, XNamespace nsd)
        {
            return ele.Element(nsd + "propstat").Element(nsd + "status").Value != "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as shown in my question, my XML content is not like that. The one I'm comparing is not an attribute and it's a sub-element.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still different. Here, `<age>` is an immediate child from `<Person>`. In my XML, it is not. This is why I included my XML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get use the linq statement as shown below

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<XElement> responseWithOut404 = 
    (from element in doc.Descendants("response")
     let xElement = element.Descendants("status").First() 
     where !xElement.Value.Contains("404")
     select element)
     .ToList();
```